# Initializing std::thread in ctor of movable class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std

I need to initialize a std::thread in ctor of class. Thread should run a member function of class itself. In ctor when trying to initialize thread, programs attemps to run member function. (Move semantic is implemented).

```
Page::Page(Motion *_parent):
    parent(_parent)
{
    std::thread x(&Page::play,this);
    starter = std::move(x);
}
```

program runs `play()` of `this` !

**EDIT** : I do this:

```
void Page::start()
{
    std::thread x(&Page::play,this);
    x.join();
}
```

And works fine but don't know if it's OK or not... Now I'm  playing with `std::bind` if it's standard way of doing, I'll replace code.

Comment: I don't get what your question is.

Comment: @kukyakya: Problem is in first line of ctor, program runs `this->play()`.

Comment: @Joachim: I can't figure it out...

Comment: @SorushRabiee How is that a problem though? It's very hard to understand your question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have a member function `play()` and a `std::thread starter` as a member of class. I want to initialize that thread with the `play` of instance.

Comment: That's what your code does already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of `std::thread` automatically starts the thread **immediately**, and the new thread then invokes the supplied function, so

```
std::thread x(&Page::play,this);
```

automatically calls `this->play()` on a new thread.

This is different from some thread libraries (such as .Net) where you must explicitly start the thread with a call to a `Start()` member function. There is no "delayed start" facility with `std::thread`.

If you don't want your thread to actually start until you call some other function, don't initialize the `std::thread` object in your constructor, instead do it in your `start()` function, as you have shown.

If you call `join()` on the thread object, then your code will wait for the thread to complete at the call to `join()`. Consequently, if you put the join immediately after constructing the thread object as in your example `start()` function then you might as well just call `play()` directly, as `start()` will not return until the thread has completed.

You shouldn't need `std::bind` with `std::thread` --- the thread constructor handles the binding automatically.

Comment: "There is no "delayed start" facility with std::thread". You can actually use yield to control when the thread starts.

Comment: Yield does not provide any control over when the thread starts. You can use a signalling mechanism such as `std::promise` and `std::future`, or `std::condition_variable`, or even a `std::atomic<bool>` flag to delay when the "important" part of the code on the new thread is run, but you cannot control when the thread itself is started.

Comment: no directly but indirectly you can for instance: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/yield/

Comment: If you checked the code, it's actually a spin-wait on a `std::atomic<bool>` flag. The yield call is just to avoid hogging the processor whilst spinning.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    Foo()
        : thread(std::bind(Foo::bar, this))        
        { }

    ~Foo() 
        { thread.join(); }

    static void bar(Foo *foo)
        { }

    std::thread thread;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
}
```